# How to use bootstrap to hide one of div when zoom browser windows size smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

I use bootstrap to design my web UI, and now I have a requirement as below:

I define the below div structure as their div ids are : **part1** and **part2**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="part1" class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        xxxx
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="part2" class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        yyy
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to hide the part1 automatically when shrink browser window size  or my phone browser , How can I achieve this effect ?

I try to add css "collapse" to **part1** as `<div id="part1" class="col-md-6 collapse">`, but it hides directly even my browser is larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a working code, I have tested..

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 visible-lg">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes , it works , but it's behavior is strange or un-expected , Since if I resize the browser on md size , it works , but when I continue resize browser size to more smaller as sm , but it can't be hidden . Do you know something about the min-size or max-size related features ? I am a fresh man on web design and bootstrap , thank you in advance .

Comment: If you need a solution using min-widtha and max-width, you need to use media queries

Comment: Could you give me a brief demo code based on bootstrap ? Thank you again .

Comment: Refer the link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile> in your media query add #urid{display:none}

Comment: This code resolves the issue with small screen sizes also, try this   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 visible-lg">.col-md-4</div>
      </div>

Comment: Thank you so much , Prasana . Seems visiable-* works as my expected . another question is : actually , we are depressed to use media query , right ? since it will have lot of mantain effort , I think .

Comment: Actually , I feel that bootstrap is fulfil my daily requirments largely with very simple solutions , and it can reduce my effort to design the web application . but How to integration and have conflict  with Jquery maybe a problem , sometimes , I want to use the Jquery UI too. Do you have more further experience ?

Answer (score 19):

#### Right Answer for Bootstrap 3

Use utility classes for showing and hiding content by decice via media query. Try to use thses on a limited basis and avoid creating entirely differnet versions of the smae site. Instead, use them to complement each device's presentation.

[image: Screenshot of Bootstrap responsive utility classes]

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

Use visiblity classes in bootstrap
hidden-phone
hidden-tablet based on your requirements

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="part1" class="col-md-6 hidden-phone">
                <div>
                    xxxx
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="part2" class="col-md-6">
                <div>
                    yyy
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions , but it still can't hidden when I resize my browser become smaller .

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? have you included bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: Hi, Prasanna , I use the bootstrap 3.0

Comment: For bootstrap 3.0 use class="hidden-sm" or "hidden-md" the previous code was for older version of bootstrap

Comment: But it still can't work , Could you provider a tested code for me ? thanks a lot .

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi Thanks for that bit of information, worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Like Prasanna mentioned, are you loading the bootstrap codes properly?